# PHP soap xml request

Tags: php, xml, soap

I have tried to looking around the web and searching a lot but I can't figure out how to do this.

I want to make a SOAP request with a header and XML code.

This is how far I have come: created a variable that holds the header info:

```
$headers = array(
        "POST /somefile.asmx HTTP/1.1",
        "Host: a ip adress",
        "Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8",
        "Content-Length: ".strlen($xml_post_string)
    );
```

and the xml I want to send looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetViVaDataT xmlns="http://www.somesite.se/somefile.wsdl">
      <PlatsId>int</PlatsId>
    </GetViVaDataT>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

But I have no idea how to go further. i'm using soap 1.2.

Comment: Have you looked at other SOAP questions on Stack Overflow? e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11502105/send-an-xml-request-to-a-another-web-server-using-soap-in-php?rq=1

Comment: Yeh I have, I actully got it to work after a long time of testing with cUrl :)

Answer (score 0):

If other people have the same problem that I have, so here is what i did to get it to work.

```
$soapAction = 'http://www.somesite.com/path/to/file/file.wsdl/function';


    $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org /soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
      <GetViVaDataT xmlns="http://www.somesite.se/somefile.wsdl">
        <PlatsId>int</PlatsId>
      </GetViVaDataT>
    </soap:Body>
   </soap:Envelope>';

    $headers = array(
        "POST /site.asmx HTTP/1.1",
        "Host: a ip adress",
        "Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8",
        "Content-Length: ".strlen($xml),
        'SOAPAction:' .$soapAction
    );

    $curlData = $xml;
    $url='http://site/file.asmx';
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,120);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_ENCODING,'xml');

    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);

    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curlData);

    $result = curl_exec($curl);
```